# How can I get a `PairSigner` for my Polkadot account from a Rust client using substrate-subxt?

Tags: substrate, rust-ink

I have a Rust CLI where I make a balance transfer from one account to another using this code https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-subxt/blob/master/examples/submit_and_watch.rs.

The `PairSigner` is generated with `let signer = PairSigner::new(AccountKeyring::Alice.pair());`. Instead of using this test Keychain with Alic, how can I use my personal Polkadot wallet account to sign the transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [sp-core](https://docs.rs/sp-core/3.0.0/sp_core/crypto/trait.Pair.html#tymethod.from_phrase), one can use `Phase::from_phrase` to accomplish this.

`let pair = Pair::from_phrase(&"menumonic".to_string(), Some("password"))?;`